# Convert temporary download links (URLs) to permanent links

Tags: download, youtube, server, youtube-data-api, download-manager

Particularly on sites like YouTube the download link is a *temporary* link which for me more often than not expires roughly after 5 hours.I like using YouTube to watch tutorials and stuff.I prefer downloading tuts overnight since watching them at HD is impossible due to a slow internet connection.

Before I sleep I pile like 10 episodes of my tutorials to my download manager , in the morning only to find a few completed and the rest failed since the link expired.

My question is how can I download seamlessly e.g

1. copy temporary link
2. paste it some where
3. wait a few secs  to mins
4. get permanent link
5. add to my download manager

How can I pull this of using a virtual private server (Mine is Windows) ,using some webgui like download manager (please suggest one as I have not found one that is easy to use) **OR** is there any other way to do this (since i don't have much storage in my VPS).

Hoping a for method that works for all site not only Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

After much scouring the web a good solution was to run Free Download Manager Remote control server or Uget on the VPS.Then use *open source file manager* scripts to access the download directory.Then there after copying the permanent link to the local download manager.